# flash disk size is not normal after using suse image writer

Tags: boot, usb-flash-drive, opensuse

Ok I don't know what to do, and decided to ask here, here's the problem :

I have a 8 GB flash disk that i use to boot image. I decided to try opensuse 12.3, and then i use unetbootin to extract it to my flash disk.

When i try to boot it says something like the machine didn't find any OS, so I do some googling and it says i have to use suse image writer to extract the image, so later my machine can detect it.

After using suse image writer, I can boot my flash disk containing opensuse, but the real problem is, the size of my flash disk is shrinked to 3.7 MB from 8 GB. I tried to format it but nothing happens.

Any hints? And sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Use [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net) from your favourite Linux distro (or boot from its own LiveCD/USB), delete all partitions from the USB stick, create a single partition and reformat using your file system of choice.